# Non-image data augmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-augmentation

I am looking for an algorithm and-or tutorial about data augmentation but all of them belong to image augmentation , is it possible to do that in other datasets ? 
I am working on parkinsons data set (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/parkinsons) and want to create an example of data aug with python , is this possible ? or should i use smt like mnist/fmnist ?

Comment: Your data seems to be sound ? if it's correct, have you tried to search "data augmentation for sound data" in google ? You can definitly do data augmentation on sound, by transforming the sound into spectrograms and then do data augmentation similar to the one on images but on the spectrogram for example. Like in this https://towardsdatascience.com/state-of-the-art-audio-data-augmentation-with-google-brains-specaugment-and-pytorch-d3d1a3ce291e for a particular example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had access to the actual voice recordings, you could apply some augmentation techniques [used in speech recognition](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-speech-recognition-e7c607482e78) and then re-extract the features such as fundamental frequency. However, since you're dealing directly with the features, augmentation is more tricky. It is possible to generate synthetic samples by interpolating between existing ones or adding noise, but since the features are highly correlated, you need a smart way of doing that (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf) for a simple approach and [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05538.pdf) for a more advanced technique). If you have a class imbalance problem, you can try simply over- or under-sampling.